# SQL Server 2017 ODBC via Rstudio or R on SSMS gets connected only to master database

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, sql-server-2017, microsoft-r

I have been working on SQL Server 2017 via R (on Rstudio as well as R on SSMS) and i am unable to connect to a specific database. I mention the database name in the connection prompt but, it gets connected only to the master database. Is there something that I am missing while connecting?

The syntax I use for connection is:

```
conn = "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};server=;Uid=uid; pwd=pwd;Database = mydb"
```

I am trying to use both RevoscaleR as well as ODBC() package in Rstudio to connect to a specific database but, it still gets connected to master database. Using RStudio connections pane, if i try to explore the other databases, it shows only dbo schemas and no other schemas even if they exist. Can someone help me in figuring out what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the login you use (the uid) is not authorized for that particular database (it is not created as a user in that database).

Some example code you can run in SSMS as - for example - sa:

```
--switch over to the database in question
USE mydb
GO
CREATE USER uid FOR LOGIN uid;
```

The above code creates a user in the database in question with the same name as the login.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Niels, Thanks for your reply!! We tried your method too and it also didn't work. One more thing i forgot to mention is that I can access the database via SQL code in SSMS, its only via ODBC or external script that i cannot connect to the specified database. Every time I use the database name in the connection prompt, I still have to provide the databasename.schema.tablename in the query.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your reply. So after you have created the user as above in the database in question; what happens if you log out of SSMS and try to log in with the username as per the created user above? Can you log in, and if you can, can you switch to the database you created the user in?

Comment: Sorry Niels. I couldn't reply after that. I worked with our database team and created a new User ODBC to get connected to that particular database and it started working fine after that